# Фильтрация коллекции с объектами, содержащими поля с одинаковыми значениями

Tags: java, java-stream

Приходит коллекция `List<Myclass> mylist`;

MyClass содержит различные поля в том числе int id.

Мне нужно оставить в mylist только те экземпляры Myclass которые имеют одинаковые поля id.

Т.е. например пришла коллекция с 10 экземплярами. в ней есть id: 0,0,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,9.

Должна остаться коллекция с 4 экземплярами Myclass с id 0, 0, 9, 9

Я пытался сделать так:

```
mylist.removeAll(mylist.stream()
                .collect(collectingAndThen(toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(comparingInt(Myclass ::getId))),
                        ArrayList::new)));
```

но не проходит.

Comment: 1) Группировать  элементы по id 2) Оставить только группы из 2 и более элементов 3) Взять из каждой группы по ревому элементу

Comment: @tym32167 Взять из каждой группы все элементы.

Comment: @Igor а, ну да, точно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Myclass> resultList = myList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Myclass::getId))
                .values().stream()
                .filter(n -> n.size() > 1)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: не работает. если к примеру есть три экземпляра класса с повторяющимися значениями то остаются только 2 последних. первый пропадает.

Comment: исправил ответ.